# Минус - синтаксическая роль.

Tags: синтаксис

**Пять минус три.** Это предложение?  Интересно, как сделать его синтаксичекий разбор.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 6):

Это незаконченное предложение. Вот если вы скажете: пять минус три - два - это будет предложение, в котором пять минус три - подлежащее, два - сказуемое.

Comment: @Ларf это все понятно. А что такое "пять минус три" даже в законченном предложении? Из чего оно состоит? Я не зря Виноградова искал.   
Кстати, насчет незаконченности - тоже поспорить можно. Что это вообще ха явление в грамматике, "незаконченное предложение"? По каким критериеям относить предложения к "незаконченным"?

Comment: В законченном предложении это подлежащее. А какое сообщение содержится в "пять минус три?" Если это и предложение, то не полное.

Comment: Что такое "неполное предложение"?
Какая информация содержится в названии фильма "Три плюс два"? 
Для матесатика - больше чем достаточная.

Answer (score 2):

Это предложение выходит за рамки традиционных синтаксических представлений. 
Об этом еще Виноградов писал. Сейчас попробую ссылку надыбать.

Угу, [нашел](http://slovari.ru/default.aspx?s=0&p=5310&0a0=11)

Влияние математического мышления ярко отражается на употреблении некоторых математических терминов в современном русском языке. Математическое выражение иногда сохраняет признаки своей морфологической обособленности. Иллюстрацией может служить слово минус. Оно имеет такие значения: 1) знак вычитания в математике, обозначаемый горизонтальной чертой (–); 2) только в единственном числе: отрицательная величина (в математике), например: минус на минус дает плюс; 3) переносно: убыток, недостаток, ущерб, например: У этой книги много минусов; Наша квартира имеет один очень существенный минус: в ней нет ванны; 4) за вычетом, если вычесть, отнять, без: Мне следует получить пятьсот рублей минус семьдесят пять рублей аванса.

*Вот это последнее употребление, перенесенное из языка математики, не умещается в систему грамматических категорий русского языка. Минус здесь не существительное, не прилагательное, но и не наречие, так как не определяет ни глагола, ни имени прилагательного, ни существительного.* Скорее всего это — количественное слово новой формации, это — математический показатель при названии числа или предмета. Совершенно аналогичную картину представляет употребление слова плюс в соответствующем значении7 .

(курсив мой - b-s)

Answer (score 2):

Мне представляется, что здесь необходимо иметь в виду сильное влияние математического мышления на язык. Оно способствовало превращению т.н. счетных единиц в особую часть речи ИМЯ ЧИСЛИТЕЛЬНОЕ со своей категориальной семантикой абстрактного числа и своими грамматическими признаками. 
В выражениях типа "пять минус три --- два", построенных по определенной схеме, также видно влияние математического мышления: обычное сложноподчиненное предложение типа "если от пяти отнять три, то получится два" (или: "если из пяти вычесть три, то получится два") заменяется очень кратким, максимально сжатым и   абсолютно точным выражением типа "пять минус три --- два", свойственным математическому языку. В выражениях используются математические термины ПЛЮС и МИНУС. Эти слова морфологически обособлены в языке, поскольку не встраиваются в систему грамматических категорий русского языка: слова ПЛЮС и МИНУС не имена существительные, не имена прилагательные, не наречия... По предположению В.В.Виноградова, "это (плюс, минус. --- В.А.) --- количественное слово новой формации, это математический показатель при названии числа или предмета..." (Виноградов В.В. Русский язык. М., 1986. --- С.243).
Что касается синтаксической функции слов, образующих предложения типа "пять минус три --- два", то, по моему мнению,  ПЯТЬ МИНУС ТРИ --- это  подлежащее (предмет речи), а ДВА --- составное именное сказуемое (предикативная характеристика предмета речи).
Данное же в вопросе сочетание слов ПЯТЬ МИНУС ТРИ --- не предложение, и поэтому сделать синтаксический разбор невозможно.

Answer (score 0):

По-моему, это обычное односоставное назывное предложение.

Comment: И что в нем главный член?

Comment: Я вижу здесь грамматическую основу, представленную только подлежащими, хотя то, что Вы написали, очень интересно. Я свой ответ писал до прочтения Вашей информации

Comment: Я не про то, кто чего написал. Тем более, что писал не я, в Виноградов.  
Я пытаюсь понять Вашу точку зрения. Вы полагаете там больше одного подлежащего (главного члена)?  Иди все вместе - подлежащее?

Comment: Да, мне кажется, что здесь только подлежащие

Answer (score 0):

Предложение - слово многозначное:1.Предложение — единица человеческой речи.2Предложение — общее количество какого-либо товара3.Предложение в музыке 4.Предложение — термин логики предикатов.
Мы соединили 2 науки, где термин предложение обозначает разные вещи. Нас интересует значение4.Предложение (в логике предикатов) — это корректно сформированная формула  , которая не содержит свободных вхождений переменных (т.е. вхождений, не находящихся в области действия каких-либо кванторов в  ).В каждой такой структуре предложение имеет единственно возможное истинностное значение(http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/).Поэтому для математики пять минус три - тоже не предложение, это часть формулы, предложением, т.е. математическим высказыванием, будет полная формула 5-3=2. Запись словами - это только запись математической формулы, а не предложение с точки зрения лингвистики:"основная синтаксическая единица, которая содержит сообщение о чем-либо, вопрос или побуждение". Предложением будет такая запись:" Если от пяти отнять три, получится два". Так и учат говорить на математике и некоторые действия описывать на ЕГЭ.Это предложение, а " Пять минус три получится два" - только мат. высказывание, которое пытается войти в наши тексты на разговорном уровне - как ошибка. Но тенденция к упрощению может , вероятно, скоро превратить его в предложение, если многие будут его употреблять, подразумевая вышесказанный смысл.

Comment: Почему "может превратить?". В учебниках в разделе "Имя числительное" такие предложения даны.

Comment: Это у какого автора? И как именно выглядит такое предложение? Со словом минус? Это нонсенс. Учёные-лингвисты это не называют предложением, а в школьной грамматике называют? Я не встречала. В песнях есть: дважды два - четыре, но это правильное предложение и с точки зрения лингвистики,и с точки зрения логики, а пять минус три получится два - логика только математическая, вместо глагола - сказуемого математич. знак. Не видела, чтобы это было нормой синтаксиса. Как пример использования числительного - возможно, но как пример предложения - странно.

Comment: Предложение типа "Пять минус три - два".

Comment: Да, такие предложения есть, но  "Пять минус три" здесь - слитное неразложимое сочетание, оно занимает позицию подлежащего, два - сказуемое. Это как раз и говорит, что такие выражения начинают входить в нашу речь, знак тире как нулевая связка оформляет сказуемое , получается предложение , а вот в виде "Пять минус три равно два" - только запись математических действий, а не сообщение. Вот из таких записей и возникла счётная форма, скажешь "равно чему?-двум" - уже нормальное сочетание, а "равно два" - счётная форма, от чего ушли, к тому и пришли

Comment: Математика действительно вторгается в грамматику. Слитные сочетания  типа "Пять минус три" заменяют целое предложение "если от пяти отнять три" или сочетания со значением "пять за вычетом трёх"(пять за минусом трёх). Кстати, у слова минус есть такое значение "вычтя..." "за вычетом" - попытка передать математич. знак.

Comment: Ну и я о том же: пять минус три - подлежащее. А говорили не бывает,нонсенс. Из практикумов в теме "Тире между подлежащим и  сказуемым":• Пять на три – пятнадцать.
• Шестью восемь – сорок восемь.
• Пять, умноженное на двенадцать – шестьдесят.
• Десять минус два – восемь.

Comment: Ну да, я с этим не спорю, полезла в дебри, потому что вопрос был о синтаксической роли слова МИНУС, а его отдельной роли в предложении нет, он входит во фразеологизм, а фразеологизм - это даже не сочетание, а заменитель слова. Я и хотела сказать, что МИНУС имеет грамматические признаки не сущ.-подлежащего, не предиката, это запись мат. знака,явление, чуждое лингвистике, но теперь ею осваивающееся,поэтому иногда выполняет роль деепричастия "вычтя" или предлога "за вычетом".

Answer (score 0):

Вставьте  эти  три  слова  в  какой-нибудь  контекст  или  речевую  ситуацию,  а  потом  и  выясняйте,  что  это  такое.  Может  это  просто  обозначение  числа  "два"  иносказательно,  может  неполное  вопросительное  предложение.  Если  "пять  минус  три"  является  аналогом  словосочетания  "пять  без  трёх",  в  котором  нет  математических  терминов,  то  что  такое  "пять  без  трёх"  без  контекста ?  Назывное ?  Неполноё ?

Answer (score 0):

Это междометие. И больше ничего.

Comment: А как вы понимаете "междометие"?